# form post variables in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery, frameworks

this is my javascript view and the controller am calling.
javascript

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var name= $('input[name=contactname]').val();
var email= $('input[name=contactemail]').val();
var message= $('textarea[name=message]').val();
$.post("index.php/homepage/sendMail",{name:name, email:email, message:message},
function(){
   $('#contactUsMask').hide();
   $('#contactAckMask').show();
   });
});
```

controller

```
$from = $_POST['email'];
$msg = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];

$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';
$config['mailpath'] = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);
$this->email->from($from, $name);
$this->email->to($to);
$this->email->subject($sub);
$this->email->message($msg);
if($this->email->send())
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    echo $this->email->print_debugger();
    return false;
}
```

i am not able to read the post variables, please help.
all efforts appreciated

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST);` outputs?

Comment: If you're using CI you should use the input class because of the security benefits it includes. To get post data use $this->input->post() instead of the global post array. However, I suspect your problem is with the JavaScript (looks like jquery to me) if the global post array is empty.

Comment: you could also assign sent object to a var like `var postData = {name:name, email:email, message:message};` and check with `console.log( postData );`, that are you really sending anything. Also you could in brwoser in `Network` tab ( usually ) what was sent and was the sent action done at all.

Comment: I'm assuming the JavaScript you posted is a snippet. You have wrapped it in the jquery ready method right?

Answer (score 0):

try to use `$("#testform").serialize()` in your post request like

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$.post("index.php/homepage/sendMail",$("#contact").serialize(),
function(){
   $('#contactUsMask').hide();
   $('#contactAckMask').show();
   });
});
```

and in your controller you will have to use `$this->input->post('email');` to get the email value ..
and as they said try to do `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: What for did you leave all the vars then? Only prevent call and post are needed in that case.

Answer (score -1):

If you are doing this cross site, you are encountering cross site issues, since .post is a wrapper for $.ajax

Comment: The url seems to be relative.